# Search Range If Blank Prompt User Intup per cell

Tags: excel, vba, input

I have a range of info and want to check it before i save it. I am having trouble with the equation to prompt the user which cell is blank and then prompt them to input the correct info. i think it is because i defined the cells as a range or i am missing something else. Once the input box pops up i am trying to inform the user on which data they are missing by offsetting the cell to the left one. The cell to the left is type of data they need to enter (like date or name). That offset cell wont display in the message of the input box either.

```
For Each CheckCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J5:J17").Cells
        If Len(Trim(CheckCell.Value)) = 0 Then
           Cellcheck.Value = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Data for" & CheckCell.Offset(Rowoffset:=0, Columnoffset:=-1).Value, "Mission Info")
        End If
    Next CheckCell
```

Comment: It's CheckCell not Cellcheck on the 3rd line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third line should be `CheckCell.Value...`, not `Cellcheck.Value...`:

```
For Each CheckCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J5:J17").Cells
    If Len(Trim(CheckCell.Value)) = 0 Then
       CheckCell.Value = Application.InputBox("Please Enter Data for " & CheckCell.Offset(Rowoffset:=0, Columnoffset:=-1).Value, "Mission Info")
    End If
Next CheckCell
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess i was staring at it to long. When you run the program the input box dose not show any text for that Checkcell.offset part of the code. That cell does have a value in in.

Comment: I closed the file and reopened it and it work great now! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Correcting the **spelling error**

```
Sub dural()
    For Each checkCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J5:J17").Cells
        If Len(Trim(checkCell.Value)) = 0 Then
           mesage = "Please Enter Data for " & checkCell.Address(0, 0)
           checkCell.Value = Application.InputBox(Prompt:=mesage, Type:=1)
        End If
    Next checkCell
End Sub
```

Change the **Type** to match your requirements.

Comment: Instead of Checkcell.address(0,0) I am wanting to return the value of that cell. But when i change it to checkcell.value i get blank in the message box.

Comment: You are absolutely correct!!  The InputBox says **which** cell needs the value *(shows the address)*  What the user types into that InputBox  **goes into** that cell!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent From what Mark said in his question, he was trying to put the contents of the cell to the left of `CheckCell` into the InputBox prompt. To make this answer match that requirement, you would need to change line 4 to: `mesage = "Please Enter Data for " & checkCell.Offset(0, -1).Value & " in cell " & checkCell.Address(0, 0)`.